# Decrypt a field from SQL Server via VB.NET and display in DataGridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption, datagridview

I am trying to decrypt two string fields that were encrypted upon insertion into the database.

They are simply name fields, so no, I won't be checking against a hashed password to ensure validity. I actually need to see the names.

The decryption method I am trying to use is from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx) and works perfectly.

Say the user is searching for someone by first name or last name. How do I use the function to return plain text in the GridView?[image: I have decrypted them in the search process.]

See below:

```
    SearchFirsttxt.Text = eFirst
    SearchLastTxt.Text = eLast

    If SearchFirsttxt.Text = "" Then
        SqlCommand.CommandText = "Select * FROM PARTICIPANT WHERE LAST_NM_TXT = '" & eLast & "';"
    ElseIf SearchLastTxt.Text = "" Then
        SqlCommand.CommandText = "Select * FROM PARTICIPANT WHERE FIRST_NM_TXT = '" & eFirst & "';"
    Else
        SqlCommand.CommandText = "Select * FROM PARTICIPANT WHERE FIRST_NM_TXT = '" & eFirst & "' and LAST_NM_TXT = '" & eLast & "';"
    End If
    'SQL Command returns rows where values in database and textboxes are equal

    dFirst = clsEncrypt.DecryptData(eFirst)
    dLast = clsEncrypt.DecryptData(eLast)
    SearchFirsttxt.Text = dFirst
    SearchLastTxt.Text = dLast

    Dim myAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand) 'holds the data
    myAdapter.Fill(dt) 'datatable that is populated into the holder (DataAdapter)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt 'Assigns source of information to the gridview (DataTable)

    SQLConnection.Close() 'Closes Connection for security measures
```

Comment: I am thinking something along the lines of Looping through the datatable, row by row, where the EMP_ID is not Null (meaning it actually has data) and decrypting row[x] only for columns(2) and (3).. I'm not quite sure how to do that though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I used, which is just modified code from: [How do I Iterate Through DataTable and Decrypt a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570196/how-do-i-iterate-through-datatable-and-decrypt-a-field)

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        dt.Rows(i)("FIRST_NM_TXT") = clsEncrypt.DecryptData(dt.Rows(i)("FIRST_NM_TXT"))
        dt.Rows(i)("LAST_NM_TXT") = clsEncrypt.DecryptData(dt.Rows(i)("LAST_NM_TXT"))
Next
```

I assume the ("FIRST_NM_TXT") must be the Column name of the particular field you're wanting to loop through and decrypt.
Edit: The format could also be `dt.Rows(i)("Index")`, not just `ColumnName`

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you are retrieving the data from your DB.

If you're populating a collection of your class, I'd extend the class to have a property that decrypts the field. So if you're  encrypted column is called Name, I'd create a read only property called NameDecrypted that runs your decryption routine on the encrypted Name property.

If you're executing SQL directly via something like a stored procecure, you could do it via a binding event on the grid. I'm not sure what grid product you're using but the one we use has an event that is fired when a cell is bound to the datasource. You could then decrypt the encrypted value that is in the grid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Cody. I will update my OP so you can see my code.

Comment: From your above code, it seems that you would add a new column to your datatable for each field that needs to be decrypted. You'd then need to loop through each row and decrypt your data and put the decrypted data in the corresponding column that you created.

Comment: The unfortunate reality of this project is that no one, aside from the single end user, is allowed to see the data. That means that at no point in time can the plain text for the "Name" fields be visible by a DBA. Do you have any opinions on that? Also, if I was told the requirements changed to encrypting everything, do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: When I referred to adding an unencrypted column to the datatable, I was referring to the .NET DataTable structure, not the table in the database. All your data can be encrypted in the DB table. You'd just need to write a helper class that can take a datatable object and decrypt all fields. Wouldn't be heard to write but it will slow down performance

Comment: I see. Thanks for replying. I am genuinely unfamiliar with this kind of stuff, as I am just getting into programming. Do you have any sample code or somewhere you can reference that might? I wouldn't have the slightest idea how to go about doing that. Performance is not an issue in this particular scenario. They know the performance will suffer due to large amounts of data encryption. Note: I have seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570196/how-do-i-iterate-through-datatable-and-decrypt-a-field and will try to run with some of that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DatagridView1.Rows
    DatagridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = Encrypt(row.Cells("Password").Value.ToString)
Next
```

Here is the code for Encrypt()

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal clearText As String) As String
    Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
    Dim clearBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText)
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, _
         &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length)
                cs.Close()
            End Using
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return clearText
End Function
```